# Best way to manage code changes for application in Amazon EC2 with Auto Scaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scalability, autoscaling, amazon-ami

I have multiple instances running behind Load balancer with Auto Scaling in AWS.

Now, if I have to push some code changes to these instances and any new instances that might launch because of auto scaling policy, what's the best way to do this?

The only way I am aware of is, to create a new AMI with latest code, modify the auto scaling policy to use this new AMI and then terminate the existing instances. But this might involve a longer downtime and I am not sure whether the whole process can be automated.

Any pointers in this direction will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What platform does that code run on, J2EE, PHP, etc? If J2EE, for example, which engine, Jetty, Tomcat, etc?

Comment: I am using ubuntu AMI with LAMP installation for a PHP application.

Answer (score 5):

The way I do my code changes is to have a master server which I edit on the code on. All the slave servers which scale then rsync via ssh by a cron job to bring all the files up to date. All the servers sync every 30 minutes +- a few random seconds to keep from accessing it at the exact same second. (note I leave the Master off of the load balancer so users always have the same code being sent to them. Similarly, when I decide to publish my code changes, I do an rsync from my test server to my master server.

Using this approach, you merely have to put the sync command in the start-up and you don't have to worry about what the code state was on the slave image as it will be up to date after it boots.

EDIT:
We have stopped using this method now and started using the new service AWS CodeDeploy which is made for this exact purpose:

http://aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/

Hope this helps.

Comment: how do you sync the slave instance to the master?

Comment: I use rsync witch is fairly simple as long as you have ssh set up with key pair authenication between the slaves and the master server. An example command: rsync -arvzi --perms --exclude ".*" -e ssh MyUser@Master.MyDomain.com:/var/www/ /var/www/

This command is run on the slave and would pull and changes from the master server. I would then have a command like this set up to run every 30 min. as a chron job. Hope that clarifies it for you.

Comment: So, I'm assuming there are never any database schema changes? Because then you'd be throwing errors on the slaves that have not yet been updated. Yeah?

Comment: We actually use DynamoDB for our database management (NoSQL). Our data structure is actually in JSON format and only store information that differs from the rows default values. This makes it so if a new value is introduced, the default value is already implied for the previous rows and it also means that the schema itself is established from the software side and gets updated at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

We configure our Launch Configuration to use a "clean" off-the-shelf AMI - we use these: http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/

One of the features of these AMIs is CloudInit - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CloudInit

This feature enables us to deliver to the newly spawned plain vanilla EC2 instance some data. Specifically, we give the instance a script to run.
The script (in a nutshell) does the following:

1. Upgrades itself (to make sure all security patches and bug fixes are applied).
2. Installs Git and Puppet.
3. Clones a Git repo from Github.
4. Applies a puppet script (which is part of the repo) to configure itself. Puppet installs the rest of the needed software modules.

It does take longer than booting from a pre-configured AMI, but we skip the process of actually making these AMIs every time we update the software (a couple of times a week) and the servers are always "clean" - no manual patches, all software modules are up to date etc.

Now, to upgrade the software, we use a local boto script.
The script kills the servers running the old code one by one. The Auto Scaling mechanism launches new (and upgraded) servers.

Make sure to use `as-terminate-instance-in-auto-scaling-group` because using `ec2-terminate-instance` will cause the ELB to continue to send traffic to the shutting-down instance, until it fails the health check.

Interesting related blog post: http://blog.codento.com/2012/02/hello-ec2-part-1-bootstrapping-instances-with-cloud-init-git-and-puppet/

Comment: Re the codento blog: It seems the reason for not simply creating an AMI snapshot to launch is insufficient: `The problem with that is that you need to repeat the process whenever you want to upgrade to a new base AMI` From an auto-scaling point of view, this is horrendously slow. I see you're killing off instances (thanks for the as vs. ec2 tip) but how about simply updating the ebs backed ec2 instance's var/www/directory repo with a git clone and let the server continue to run?  New auto-scaled instances would pull from there too.  Is there a problem with such a simple approach?

Comment: Obviously patching the existing servers is faster. I'm not sure how you would sync the ELB with the web server restart to manage no end user down time. Also, I have no problem with roughly 5 minutes from the usage-peak-alarm until I have as many servers as I want joining the pack. It is simply fast enough in my use case. and I sound the alarm earlier in most cases.

Answer (score -2):

It appears you can manually double auto scaling group size, it will create EC2 instances using AMI from current Launch Configuration. Now if you decrease auto scaling group back to the previous size, old instances will be killed and only instances created from a new AMI will survive.